# Sitefinity4.2 Admin is not working in IE7/IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, sitefinity

We are facing an issue in IE7 and IE8 with Sitefinity 4.2 Admin side.
We can create the pages but its not allowing me to edit page like adding layout or widget.
Its not  publishing or loading any of the pages we created.But everything is working fine in other Browsers.
As if now nothing is working for Admin side,every time its coming with random issues.
JavaScript enabled and Silverlight plugin 4 is also installed. Still its not working.

Please let us know we can fix this in any manner.
We will appreciate your fast response as we are only day remaining to deliver our product.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Details about any Javascript errors that are thrown could help.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd recommend posting this to the [Sitefinity forums](http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/forums.aspx).  Nothing against StackOverflow, but your question will get a lot more attention on those forums.

--

Beyond that, both IE7 and IE8 are [formally supported](http://www.sitefinity.com/resources/system-requirements.aspx) by the Sitefinity UI.  However, it's important to keep in mind that your web site's design will get co-mingled with Sitefinity's admin UI during page editing.  Which means it's possible for your web site design to create browser glitches.  I've personally broken the backend interface with my own custom templates & styling.  A general good strategy is to avoid being greedy with your CSS styling.

For example, do this:

```
#main div {
   padding: 1em;
}
```

Instead of this:

```
div {
   padding: 1em;
}
```

This is an extreme example, but it shows how to limit your personal CSS styling from impacting Sitefinity's administrative interface.  Best wishes.

Comment: Thanks for your response.Am able to fix this,the javascript error was stopping page from loading further.Then i fixed that javascript error then it got fixed.